# Copying from /data/app folder using superuser

Tags: android, android-runtime, android-internal-storage

I am trying to copy files from /data/app folder, but facing the following issues, please advice.

```
Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new     DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream);
```

1. Error is, Required : android.os.Process, Found : java.lang.Process in the first line of the code.
2. Cannot resolve symbol, getOutputStream in the second line.

Kindly let me know why these issues occur, and how do I resolve them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.os.Process, Found : java.lang.Process

Be sure to import the right class.

```
import java.lang.Process;
```

Or declare your process like this :

```
java.lang.Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

> Cannot resolve symbol, getOutputStream

`getOutputStream` is a method then you need to add `()` to be able to compile your code.

```
DataOutputStream os = new     DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added the import and also the '()', but still those two errors occur.

Comment: Thank u so much for the help!